# Timeout hashtable Java

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, timeout, hashtable

I'm still learning programming and came across an interesting  task I must do. Your help will be much appreciated as i have no idea how to implement such task and i have been battling with it for a couple of days now...

A class which stores elements in a Hashtable for a defined amount of time. After the time runs out, the value and key must be deleted. Accessing or manipulating a value, resets the timer for that value. All i managed to figure out was use a timer, but I have no idea where to start from . I can't use anything else like Guava MapMaker suggested in other answers.

I'd appreciate your ideas and help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class with a concurrent `Hashmap` with methods like put, get and remove.

When putting a element, add it to the map and schedule a runnable to remove it after a amount of time. See the `SchedulerExecutorService` class to do that.

The `submit()` method of the executor service returns a Future which lets you to cancel the removing process if necessary.

Comment: thank you man. Will check it out! Do you know any good sources on similar problems like that? My background is not remotely related to programming and computer science and would love to check out some reads on the matter.

Comment: Honestly, i would use Guava library which provides a Cache implementation. See https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained  (If you have no more problem, please consider to accept an answer for the topic to help other people with same question to find it easily)

Answer (score 0):

If rolling-your-own solution this will likely involve storing entries in a `ConcurrentMap` which have a timestamp. You'll then likely have a scheduled job (see [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)) which removes stale entries.

This problem has been solved many times by many cache implementations. See Guava's [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) for one such implementation.

Comment: thank you man. Will check it out! Do you know any good sources on similar problems like that? My background is not remotely related to programming and computer science and would love to check out some reads on the matter.